# Plus sign in codeigniter URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

My first codeigniter project, and I hope to find some help with this url and function argument issue.

This is the url that I have a problem with:
http://localhost/mysite/info/test/abc+xyz (typed in straight into the address bar)

Controller:info
function:test

```
function test($myargs)
{
    echo $myargs;
}
```

I need the function to echo "abc+xyz" But it CI converts the plus sign to an underscore "abc_xyz" , which I dont want.

Things I have tried :
I tried changing

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
TO
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~+%.:_\-';
```

no joy !
Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

EDIT : My htaccess is the usual one to remove index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Before making the change to the permitted_uri_chars, if I try to access a URL with the + sign I get the error 'An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.'.  Do you get this too?  After adding the + sign to the list it works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe you could also post any rewrite rules that you have defined in your .htaccess file.  Perhaps your URL is being rewritten before it hits CodeIgniter.

Comment: You are right, Stephan. I never bothered to check the htaccess. Though I have just the usual htaccess to remove index.php, it seems that is the culprit. When I use index.php in the url, codeigniter doesnt seem to have a problem with the plus sign. But then I donot want index.php in my url, so the issue still persists

Comment: I don't know what the problem is with your htaccess file. In the meantime I'll post my htaccess file so you can check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said above in the comments, the problem might be the way the URL is getting rewritten by Apache mod_rewrite.  Here is the htaccess file that works ok on my installation.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is the same that is proposed in the CodeIgniter user guide.

Your htaccess file wouldn't work for me.  I needed to remove the ? from the URL that it was generating for it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

When I made this change everything worked fine.